# Problems after upgrading from Lubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS

Tags: lubuntu

Selected items in Dialogue boxes not highlighted!
No separating border lines in programmes! Horizontal & Vertical bars not coloured!
Thunderbird-Mail & Firefox Browser shows pages 
a) without separating border lines
b) without highlighting selected fields and registers
c) without highlighting selected text in the address field and in the page

What is wrong?
Ricky

Comment: You should add a few screenshots for us to see. Use imgur.com if you can't add them to your question.

Comment: How do I just add the screenshots to my question?

Comment: Edit your question. Click on the small graphic icon at the top of the window. Click BROWSE and locate your screenshot. Then ADD screenshot. If your rep won't let you do it that way, use imgur.com, and post your URL link instead.

Comment: I see several icons but NOT a graphic icon at the top of the page.

Comment: The Problem is systemwide and occurs on all existing accounts, except Admin!



Question: If I delete the non-admin Account and create a new non-admin account, would the new account automatically overwrite the space freed up by the deleted account, because I have limited memory space?

Comment: The graphic icon is the one that has the little mountain range in it. Have you added any themes to your computer, or done any customization?

Comment: I don't see an icon with a mountain range. The icons on top are : my account, number of badges, recent inbox messages, reputation changes, help and a list of stack exchange sites.

Comment: I have not added any themes or customized. With the Version 16.04 LTS all was OK. since Upgrading to 18.04 LTS, the problems occured systemwide, also in the properties section and elsewhere in dialogue boxes with selections not being highlighted.

Comment: The "add graphic icon" appears at the top of the **edit** window [here](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1126171/edit). Still looking for a screenshot. What video driver are you running? What video card make/model? On your login screen, is there a cogwheel icon? If so, what desktop environment have you selected? You don't want Wayland, if that's a choice.

Comment: Thanks, found the icon, but in the meantime I found a solution to the problem; I changed the Theme in the look & feel section of SystemPreferences and all went OK. Thanks anyway, Ricky

Comment: Ah, so it WAS a theme problem. Did all accounts, except admin, use the same theme? You changed the theme from WHAT to WHAT?

Comment: Yes, Admin ha Lubuntu Default
The other account had Lubuntu Dark Panel, changed to Crux and the on the Colour-Setting "Use relevant colour scheme" activated.

Comment: OK, I'll put together a real quickie answer that you can accept, ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

Bottom line, it was a theme problem. All accounts, except for Admin, used the same bad theme. Admin worked fine. All other accounts failed. Reset theme in all non-admin accounts, and it all works again.

Comment: Okay, accepted!